# Ember serve Build Error (EslintValidationFilter)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

running `ember serve` i get the following error message

```
Build Error (EslintValidationFilter) in components/type-compte.js

Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Stack Trace and Error Report: C:\...Temp/error.dump.d4e5703d56fd78302521e967efca5c25.log
```

the stack trace containe :

> ERROR Summary:
>
> - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
>     at CallExpression (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint-plugin-ember\lib\rules\require-super-in-init.js:92:60)
>     at listeners.(anonymous function).forEach.listener (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\safe-emitter.js:47:58)
>     at Array.forEach ()
>     at Object.emit (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\safe-emitter.js:47:38)
>     at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\node-event-generator.js:251:26)
>     at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\node-event-generator.js:280:22)
>     at NodeEventGenerator.enterNode (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\node-event-generator.js:294:14)
>     at CodePathAnalyzer.enterNode (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\code-path-analysis\code-path-analyzer.js:608:23)
>     at Traverser.enter [as _enter] (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\linter.js:865:28)
>     at Traverser._traverse (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\node_modules\eslint\lib\util\traverser.js:132:14)
> - codeFrame: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
> - errorMessage: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `EslintValidationFilter` plugin. ðŸ’¥ Cannot read property 'body'
>     of undefined
> - errorType: Build Error
> - location:
>
>   - column: [undefined]
>   - file: components/type-compte.js
>   - line: [undefined]
>   - treeDir: C:\Users\PC\Desktop\dev\github\wikicours\tmp\broccoli_persistent_filtereslint_validation_filter-input_base_path-QtE3OUt9.tmp
> - message: Build Canceled: Broccoli Builder ran into an error with `EslintValidationFilter` plugin. ðŸ’¥

and `type-compte.js` contente is :

```
export default Component.extend({
    init:computed('membre.typecompte',function(){
        this._super(...arguments);
        var membre = this.get('membre');
        console.log('membre : ', membre);
        var typecompte = membre.get('typecompte');
        console.log('typecompte : ', typecompte);
        var tc ='';
        if(typecompte===0){
           tc = 'enseignant';
        }else if(typecompte===1){
            tc = 'modirateur';
        }else if(typecompte===2){
            tc = 'administrateur';
        }
        this.set('typeCompte',tc);
    }),
});
```

Comment: init can't be a computed property. Init has to be a function and you have to call _super.

Comment: thank's this working :) , put it as an answer please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init can't be a computed property. Init has to be a function and you have to call _super